# How do you do preloading of components

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.1

I would like to know how do you do pre-loading of components in sitecore 7.1?

What I tried so far:

1. Create a standard value for the page.
2. Then modify the presentation details of the standard value.
3. Then add components that I want preloaded in the page.
4. Then create a Branch for the page.
5. Use the Branch to create the page.

This works fine except when I add new components in the page's standard value, all existing page is affected with my changes.

What I need to know - is there away that the old page is not affected by my changes in the standard value?

Is there a way only the new page that I create is affected when I modify the pre-loading of components in my page?

Your input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things one should consider:

1. If there current Sitecore installation is upgraded from 6.4 or prior version to your current version; the item's layout deltas might be an issue. You will have to check the raw values of the Layout details field and figure it out.
2. Any changes made on the Layout Details on Standard Values do get cascaded down to the items created from that specific Template.
3. If you don't want these changes to get inherited try multiple inheritance. And change the template of those items created.
4. Lastly, if the above doesn't work, try creating a new template with the changes you want and change the Template of those items created.

Hope the above helps. Share any further questions you might have or even if the above haven't answered your questions.

Happy Sitecoring!

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of **__Standard Values** is automatic update of existing items.

In this case, you should not configure the item's layout in the __Standard Values.

You need to use **Branch** and configure layout in the *Page* item instead of __Standard Values.

[image]